# Google +1 count is different in my app and on play

Tags: android, google-plus

I integrated google +1 feature in my app.
I wrote following code

in onCreate()

```
        mPlusOneButton = (PlusOneButton) findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Refresh the state of the +1 button each time the activity receives focus.
        String appPackageName = getPackageName();
        mPlusOneButton.initialize("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ragini.mtrackers", 0);
    }
```

In my app the +1 count 3 while on URL https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ragini.mtrackers   +1 count is 11.

I can not find waht mistake I am commiting.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web version of the +1 button is actually using `https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ragini.mtrackers` instead of `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ragini.mtrackers` and they have different +1 counts.